# Create dataframe from a dictionary in python when the key is a byte?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, byte, avro

I want to create a dataframe from spesific data inside a dictionary. The key is a byte, and I don't understand how to get the information "out of the byte in a usefull way". If I can get the data I need into a dataframe I would know how to handle it (sort, plot etc.)

I have this dictionary:

```
{'SequenceNumber': 2654504175, 'Offset': '67826126730624', 'EnqueuedTimeUtc': '7/10/2020 1:18:00 PM', 'SystemProperties': {}, 'Properties': {}, 'Body': b'{"id": "MicroSCADA OPC DA.S_M.APL.1.P.P_R_P.1", "ts": "2020-07-10T13:17:24.654000", "value": 1.1293551921844482, "status_code": 0}'}
```

It is a result from reading one datapoint in an avro file. The data I need is inside 'Body'.

I go:

```
x=my_dict.get("Body)
```

the result is:

```
b'{"id": "MicroSCADA OPC DA.S_M.APL.1.P.P_R_P.1", "ts": "2020-07-10T13:17:24.654000", "value": 1.1293551921844482, "status_code": 0}'
```

I would like to sort the data into a dataframe with coulmns "id", "ts", "value", and "status code". How can I do this?

I have also tried pandavro, but the byte is still "locking" the data I need together. I have tried converting the byte to string, but then the key and it's value dosen't naturally belong together any more.

How to solve this in a best possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the byte string to a string, evaluate it and convert it into a dataFrame:

```
dic = {'SequenceNumber': 2654504175, 'Offset': '67826126730624', 'EnqueuedTimeUtc': '7/10/2020 1:18:00 PM', 'SystemProperties': {}, 'Properties': {}, 'Body': b'{"id": "MicroSCADA OPC DA.S_M.APL.1.P.P_R_P.1", "ts": "2020-07-10T13:17:24.654000", "value": 1.1293551921844482, "status_code": 0}'}

d = eval(dic["Body"].decode("utf-8"))

df = pd.DataFrame([list(d.values())],columns = list(d.keys()))

df
```

Output:

```
    id                                      ts                          value    status_code
0   MicroSCADA OPC DA.S_M.APL.1.P.P_R_P.1   2020-07-10T13:17:24.654000  1.129355    0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Now my issue is that append gives me trouble with datatypes.

Comment: Please upvote or give it as solution then. What do you mean with append?To Add more dictionaries? I would suggest to append them to d as list of lists and then create the dataFrame.

Comment: I loop through an avro file returning many dictionaries as the one above. I would like to pick out the 'Body' part from all dictionaries and put into one single dataframe, with columns that is equal to your result. So, your solution works, but now I am not able to append. A list solution is probably better to save processing, but how to do this?

Comment: Just keep adding your dictionaries to a list `d_list`, then just do `df = pd.DataFrame(d_list)`

Comment: I am in way over my head here, but this is really helpfull. d_list.append(d) inside my for loop, then df=pd.DataFrame(d_list) works perfect! Thank you so much!